# UWP shortcut is not created correctly if script is run from MS Configuration System

Tags: shell, uwp, sccm, shortcut-file

I used this code to create a shortcut for a UWP app in the startup folder which when i run locally as USER, it works fine and create a working shortcut.

But, when i push this code from SCCM, a non-working shortcut will be created with less size but exact same permissions,owner, and everything else.My guess is that, SYSTEM account that sccm runs the script as doesn't see the application which is installed in User Profile.

The environment have a policy where users usually don't have access to CMD or Powershell. In this case, it will also fail as users don't have access to to the consoles.

```
On Error Resume Next
strStartMenuLocation = "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\"
set objWShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appData = objWShell.expandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramData%")
proloc = appData & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(proloc & "\{Shortcut_Name}.lnk")
'Define where you would like the shortcut to point to. This can be a program, Web site, etc.
oShellLink.TargetPath = "shell:AppsFolder\{AppFamilyName}!{AppID}"
oShellLink.Description = ""
oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = allusersdesktop
oShellLink.Save
```

Any suggestions on how to create this shortcut?

Comment: Your guess is correct, applications are registered per user. Can you run a program when the user logs on to create the shortcut?

Comment: The issue is that, Users don't have access to cmd or powershell, I tried to execute it in a console or win32 application as a process but it didn't work.

Comment: But can you have the user run a program at login? Or can you install a program and then give them a shortcut to that program that will create the UWP shortcut?

Comment: The only thing I know that can operate with the knowledge of the user context but still use admin rights are gpos but I am not sure if this is true for semething new like apps (gpo functionality was not really update a lot with such featuers) so you would have to try. Another idea would be to create all the shortcuts as user and store on a central location then copy from there with system account